# How to handle socket timeout in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, timeout

I'm using Python 3.4 on an RaspberryPi to read and upload data to Weather Underground. It works great most of the time, but occasionally either my internet connections is poor or Weather Underground servers are slow  The other day I got this error:

socket.timeout: _ssl.c:584: The handshake operation timed out

I have try/except code, but it didn't match with any of the exceptions. I assumed the last "except:" would have caught the error, but I guess not. Should I just add "except socket.timeout:"?

```
try:
    r = requests.get(full_URL, timeout=5) # send data to WU

    # If uploaded successfully, website will reply with 200
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return(True)
    else:
        print('Upload Error: {}  {}'.format(r.status_code, r.text))
        return(False)

except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    print("Upload Error in upload2WU() - ConnectionError")
    return(False)

except requests.exceptions.NewConnectionError:
    print("Upload Error in upload2WU() - NewConnectionError")
    return(False)

except requests.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
    print("Upload Error in upload2WU() - MaxRetryError")
    return(False)

except socket.gaierror:
    print("Upload Error in upload2WU() - socket.gaierror")
    return(False)

except:
    print("Upload Error in upload2WU() - other")
    return(False)
```

I do have two other places I'm using requests.get(), but they both use try: and except:

```
try:
    response = requests.get(getUrl, timeout=5).json()
    if len(response) > 1:
        if isNumber(response['current_observation']['precip_today_in']):
            daily_rain = float(response['current_observation']['precip_today_in'])
            print('Suntec station daily rain={}'.format(daily_rain))  
            return(daily_rain)

    return(ERR_INVALID_DATA)

except:
    print("Error in WU_download.py getDailyRain() - failed get() request")
    return(ERR_FAILED_GET)
```

Here's the other one:

```
    try:
        response = requests.get(getUrl, timeout=5).json()
        if len(response) > 1: # valid response returns 3, if there's an error, the len() is 1
            if isNumber(response['current_observation']['pressure_in']):
                nearby_pressure = float(response['current_observation']['pressure_in'])
                nearby_last_update_time = int(response['current_observation']['observation_epoch'])
                if(nearby_pressure) > 25: # a pressure less than 25 inHg isn't gonna be valid
                    return(nearby_pressure)

        # Didn't get a valid pressure. Try the next station in WU_STATIONS tuple
        print("Couldn't get pressure data from {}".format(WU_STATIONS[i]))
        nearby_pressure = ERR_INVALID_DATA
        nearby_last_update_time = 0
        i = i + 1
        time.sleep(10)

    except:
        print("Error in WU_download.py getPressure(), failed get request for station {}".format(WU_STATIONS[i]))
        i = i + 1
        if (i >= len(WU_STATIONS)):
            return(ERR_FAILED_GET)
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the part that is erroring? `except` should catch any exception

Comment: I use requests.get() in two other places, but they both have except: to catch errors.  I edited the original post to include them.